# Do I need an else-if statement here or is it unnecessary?

Tags: php, laravel

This functionality is used to delete an image. The first if redirects back if the user who is trying to delete the image is not the author of the image or an admin, the else-if checks if the user has admin role and if he does, the image gets deleted. And finally if the user is not an admin and is the author of the image, the last bit of code deletes the image as well.

Now my question is, do I even need the else if part of the code? Can I just have 1 small if statement that redirects if the user is neither an admin nor the author and then delete the image since if the user passes the first if, he's definitely either admin or an author.

```
public function deleteImage($imageId){
        $image = Image::where('id', $imageId)->first();
        if (!Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
            if (Auth::user() != $image->user){
                return redirect()->back();
            }
        } else if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')) {
            $imageName = $image->image_file_name;
            $image->tags()->detach();
            $image->delete();
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/'.$imageName);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$imageName);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$imageName);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$imageName);
            $imageChildren = Image::where('parent_id', $image->id)->get();
            foreach ($imageChildren as $imageChild) {
                Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
                Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
                Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
                Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
                $imageChild->delete();
            }
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
        $imageName = $image->image_file_name;
        $image->tags()->detach();
        $image->delete();
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/'.$imageName);
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$imageName);
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$imageName);
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$imageName);
        $imageChildren = Image::where('parent_id', $image->id)->get();
        foreach ($imageChildren as $imageChild) {
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
            Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
            $imageChild->delete();
        }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should do the same thing. You did not need the else if since it will always performs the same execution once the first condition is met. I also concatenated the first condition to include the check for author vs image user

```
public function deleteImage($imageId){
    $image = Image::where('id', $imageId)->first();
    if (!Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin') && Auth::user() != $image->user) {
            return redirect()->back();
    }
    $imageName = $image->image_file_name;
    $image->tags()->detach();
    $image->delete();
    Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/'.$imageName);
    Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$imageName);
    Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$imageName);
    Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$imageName);
    $imageChildren = Image::where('parent_id', $image->id)->get();
    foreach ($imageChildren as $imageChild) {
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/thumbnails/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/specificImages/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
        Storage::delete('public/uploads/images/miniImages/'.$imageChild->image_file_name);
        $imageChild->delete();
    }
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought so. Thanks.